# Unable to process "subbasin parameters from raster"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, hec-geohms

I was wondering why do i have a different interface for subbasin parameters from raster window. .

i image is displayed below.
[image]

instead of this. .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Once you choose 'Select HMS Processes' and select the appropriate processes then the options in the window should change.  You may run into other issues when running the process which can range from ArcMap licensing to the location of files.  HEC-GeoHMS does not always appreciate working from network drives.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the [tool's documentation](http://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-geohms/documentation/HEC-GeoHMS_Users_Manual_10.1.pdf) is not correct. You can report bugs [here](http://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-geohms/bug_report.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem today and I tried @hornet's answer but useless. Here is my answer:

My ArcGIS is 10.2.

Just do not enable the Background Processing option on the Geoprocessing Options editor(1.Go to Geoprocessing, Geoprocessing Options…
2.Make sure the Enable checkbox is not checked under Background Processing.), restart the software and do 'Select HMS Processes' again, the other options appear!